# Meaning of "boosting cat food from someone"

Tags: expressions, slang

In the 'The Panic in Needle Park' movie, one of the actors tell someone the following on the phone:

> No, man. I didn't boost any cat food from you.

What does it mean? It doesn't seem to be a very common expression either.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[As cornbread ninja says](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/65255/3231), *boost* is to 'steal'.  *Cat food* is, according to [Urban Dictionary option 6 is 'crack cocaine'.](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Cat%20Food)

So, the overall meaning is:

> No, man. I didn't steal any crack from you.

Answer (score 2):

To *[boost](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/boost)* something means to steal it.

> Slang . to engage in stealing, especially shoplifting.